# Regex Search in Multiple PyMongo Document Fields

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

### The Goal

Search the corpus of Enron emails to find emails to and from Ken Lay, securities fraudster extraordinaire.

### The Data

One such email document, of 500k+ emails named `workdocs`, are structured like below:

One such document:

```
 {'headers': {'To': 'eric.bass@enron.com', 'Subject': 'Re: Plays and other information', 'X-cc': '', 'X-To': 'Eric Bass', 'Date': 'Tue, 14 Nov 2000 08:22:00 -0800 (PST)', 'Message-ID': '<6884142.1075854677416.JavaMail.evans@thyme>', 'From': 'michael.simmons@enron.com', 'X-From': 'Michael Simmons', 'X-bcc': ''}, 'subFolder': 'notes_inbox', 'mailbox': 'bass-e', '_id': ObjectId('4f16fc97d1e2d32371003e27'), 'body': "the scrimmage is still up in the air...\n\n\nwebb said that they didnt want to scrimmage...\n\nthe aggies  are scrimmaging each other... (the aggie teams practiced on \nSunday)\n\nwhen I called the aggie captains to see if we could use their field.... they \nsaid that it was tooo smalll for us to use...\n\n\nsounds like bullshit to me... but what can we do....\n\n\nanyway... we will have to do another practice Wed. night....    and I dont' \nknow where we can practice.... any suggestions...\n\n\nalso,  we still need one  more person..."}
```

The fields I'm interested in are `{'To':...,'From':...,'X-cc':...,'X-bcc':...}`, which are found in the field `'headers'`.

### The Implementation (and error)

Doing a search across the entire document for `'klay@enron'` seems to work using `workdocs.find({'$text':{'$search':'klay@enron.com'}})` but I'm interested in capturing many possible email aliases with a regex.  How do I find the documents that match a regex `ken_email` (below) in the fields `To`, `From`, `X-bcc`, and `X-cc`?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient  
import re
re_email = '^(K|Ken|Kenneth)[A-Z0-9._%+-]*Lay@[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$'
ken_email = re.compile(re_email, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: I think what you need here is [Wildcard Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes)

Comment: Not sure that works for me.  This index allows for text search on all fields with string content.  I'm looking at 4 specific fields, mentioned above.

Comment: `'((?:K((en)?neth)?)[A-Z0-9._%+-]*Lay@[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only search those four fields, you can use:

```
(?:to|from|x-b?cc)'\s*:\s*'K[A-Z0-9._%+-]*Lay@[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}
```

That version removes the capture group around his first name, which is unnecessary for the match to happen. (It would be faster to extract after the regex is finished.)

I'm also not convinced it's necessary to validate the email address. You're already looking in fields that should have nothing but email addresses. You could further shorten the regex:

```
(?:to|from|x-b?cc)'\s*:\s*'K[A-Z0-9._%+-]*Lay
```

This will have the added bonus of matching `klay123@example.com`

---

It's not terribly efficient (especially with long strings of text), but there are some ways to speed it up. The easiest way is to remove the body beforehand. (This may also help prevent false positives.) You could just remove everything after the first `}`.

Just for kicks, here's a regex to match that:

```
\}.*
```

Simply replace with an empty string to remove it.